# problem into login from sql server management studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

this is the error message:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to DESKTOP-22EMO4E.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The system cannot find the file specified

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyPCo.png)

Comment: Is it a server on LAN or your local server, if local did you tried with "."

Comment: see whether the sql server service is running. You can check in the `sql server configuration manager` or `services.msc`

Comment: As per the error, "Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."...those are the steps you need to take to resolve it. Did you do that? Is there anything in there that you don't understand how to do?

Comment: There are many many online troubleshooting guides to this error. Please try one